# datatables editor query where clause list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, datatables, where-clause

I am trying to put a List into a datatables Editor .Where clause. Something like:
    Select * from x where x.col in (y,z)

Here is my current code:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        var Usn01 = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
        var filter = from s in db.usersDbs join t in db.dimTeamLeadDbs on 
        s.teamID equals t.teamID where s.usID==Usn01 select t.teamID;
        var filter1 = filter.FirstOrDefault();
        var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
        var formData = HttpContext.Request.Form;

        using (var db = new Database(settings.DbType, 
        settings.DbConnection))
            {
                var response = new Editor(db, "users", "usID")
                    .Model<usersDb>()
                    .Where("teamID",filter1)
                    .Process(formData)
                    .Data();
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
    }
```

I basically want to change a filter1 from

```
filter.FirstOrDefault();
```

to

```
filter.ToList();
```

and put that into a where clause, which obviously does not work.
I really have no idea how to approach this.

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards,
Boris.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` returns first scalar value inside collection, `ToList()` returns entire collection values as `IEnumerable`. Are you want to use filter by collection values instead of single value then (use `foreach` loop to iterate every values if it's true)?

Comment: Crossed my mind to use `foreach` , but I still have no idea how to implement that in datatables `.Where` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crossed my mind that I can actually answer this now in case anyone needs it.

The code that gave me the result that I wanted is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Usn01 = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
        var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
        var formData = HttpContext.Request.Form;

        using (var db = new Database(settings.DbType, settings.DbConnection))
            {

            var response = new Editor(db, "users", "usID")
                    .Model<usersDb>()
                    .Where(x => x.Where("teamID", "(SELECT teamID FROM dimTeamLead 
                                        WHERE userID = '" + Usn01 + "')", "IN", false))
                    .Where(y => y.Where("IsActive",1));

            var resp = Json(response.Process(formData)
                   .Data(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return resp;
        }
    }
```